# Evaluating and returning the value of a function over an array generated by iteration

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, iteration

I'm currently writing a block of code that computes the non-parametric bootstrap of a set of samples over patients.  I have written the block so it is only called when I reject the null of the kurtosis test (as it is unfeasible at this stage to consider more intensive exploratory methods).  Here is the construction of the current code block (as a side not-I don't think that I can provide my actual data-for practical reasons and I don't own it, so I'll try to be as specific as possible)

```
#create the list of subject ids
SUB_IDS=['values']
# this is a pandas data frame of all subjects' information.  Columns are: 
#Sub_ID, NG,C,ER
asbs=pd.DataFrame(['Values'])
for x in SUB_IDS:

    x_data=asbs[asbs['SUB_ID']==x]

    x_ng=x_data['NG']
    x_c=x_data['C']
    x_er=x_data['ER']

    a,b = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_NG)
    c,d = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_C)
    e,f = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_ER)
    kurtosis_scores.append([x,a,b,c,d,e,f])
    # for somplicity we'll only focus on bootstrapping one feature variable
    if b <=.05:
        mean=x_ng.mean()
    else:
        sampled_means=[]
        for x in range(1,10000):
            g=np.random.choice(x_NG,size=len(x_NG),replace=True)
            print(g)
            g=np.mean(g)
            sampled_means.append(g)
```

My code runs smoothly until the last block-when I want to take the mean of the sampled means and append the value to a list with the subject id (and the other means of the bootstrapped values after I compute those-I left that bit out for readability).Every time I use the np.mean function on sampled_means, I get 0 (which makes sense, python is evaluating it before iteration).

What is the best way to "freeze" the array after I update the values through the for loop and pass the statistic to an array?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Can you not apply `np.mean` on `sampled_means` outside and after your `for` loop?

Comment: Hey! thanks  for the reply!  I've tried something similar, however-wouldn't i need to create an if loop telling python to return either the mean of sampled_means or mean pending the value of b?  Is this the best way to do it for large number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#create the list of subject ids
SUB_IDS=['values']
# this is a pandas data frame of all subjects' information.  Columns are: 
#Sub_ID, NG,C,ER
asbs=pd.DataFrame(['Values'])
for x in SUB_IDS:

    x_data=asbs[asbs['SUB_ID']==x]

    x_ng=x_data['NG']
    x_c=x_data['C']
    x_er=x_data['ER']

    a,b = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_NG)
    c,d = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_C)
    e,f = sp.stats.kurtosistest(x_ER)
    kurtosis_scores.append([x,a,b,c,d,e,f])
    # for somplicity we'll only focus on bootstrapping one feature variable
    if b <=.05:
        mean=x_ng.mean()
    else:
        sampled_means=[]
        for x in range(1,10000):
            g=np.random.choice(x_NG,size=len(x_NG),replace=True)
            print(g)
            g=np.mean(g)
            sampled_means.append(g)
        mean=sampled_means.mean()
```